# Sonoma Python 3.8 was manually installed yet system shows 3.9.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew, pyenv, macos-sonoma

I have a mac running on Sonoma OS. I know it comes with python automatically, but I need a version 3.8 or less for some projects Im working on for school. However, I have installed 3.8 using homebrew which was installed, but the version of python didnt change. I've tried to update it using pyenv and I haven't been able to update the version. The crazy thing is that even though the version is stated as 3.9.6, if I look for it, I can't find it.

Here is what I did so far:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install python@3.8

$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.6

$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

$ which python3.8
/usr/local/bin/python3

$ which python3.9
python3.9 not found

$ brew install pyenv

echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
Restart your shell so the path changes take effect
exec "$SHELL"
---> this came from an answer to another thread about downgrading python

$ pyenv install 3.8

$ pyenv global 3.8

$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.6

$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

$ which python3.8
/usr/local/bin/python3

$ which python3.9
python3.9 not found
```

Comment: check if pyenv is install correctly or not. after installing python 3.8 with pyenc, do check which python is it pointing to the python in the .pyenv folder or not. after that set global env with correct version no ie `pyenv global 3.8.18`  and you can still use python in system using command, `python3.8` or `python38`

Answer (score 0):

The `pyenv global` commend should be given a list which python versions you have available, in this case `pyenv global 3.8 3.9` would work better.

You can then use:

```
python --version
python3.8 --version
python3.9 --version
```

Note that you can add a `.python-version` file in your project directory to specify which version of python it used when running from that directory.
Also note that in your example above `which python3.8` gives a different location `/usr/local/bin/python3` to `which python3` which gives `/usr/bin/python3` (not in the **`local`** subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see, I ran python3.9 --version and it was not found, python3.8 --version was. But I dont understand why when I run python3 --version I get "Python 3.9.6" and not Python 3.8.18. Any ideas?

Comment: You will not get a `python3.9` until you have included it in the `pyenv globals` Why are you not running `python3.8 --version` ?

Comment: Sorry,  I think there is a miss understanding. When I type the command "python3 --version", I get the version as 3.9. That is not what I need. I need version 3.8. I have used homebrew to install the specific 3.8 version. I also used "pyenv install 3.8" and "pyenv global 3.8". Yet, again, when I run the command "python3 --version" I still get version 3.9. The weird thing is that if I run the command "where python3.9" I get a notification saying that version 3.9 was not found. When I run the command "where python3.8" it shows me where it is. So I don't understand what is going on.